# What is the best way to remove spray paint from a blacktop driveway?

Tags: cleaning, driveway

I have an area on my blacktop driveway that some kids thought needed some spray paint, what is the best way to remove it without damaging the blacktop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything you do to dissolve the paint or with a pressure washer will also remove some asphalt.

I'd vote for a good pressure washer, as tar can be messy stuff since it too will probably dissolve under the action of paint stripper. Rent one if necessary, BEFORE the paint has had time to harden is best.

Once that is done, however, you will still be left with an image of what you stripped off. So I'd next take the opportunity to apply some blacktop sealer to the entire driveway.

Finally, ensure that the kids who did it will not repeat the action. Their paying for the work will help in that respect. If they are required to help do the repair itself, that would be best.

Comment: Good luck catching the kids that did it.

Answer (score 5):

Black spray paint?

Comment: As silly of an idea as it may sound, this is actually pretty clever

Answer (score 1):

I'm betting that a pressure washer would remove it. It might also remove the blacktop though. It would also be very time consuming. You might be better off using a solvent.

Answer (score 0):

[One web site](http://www.ehow.com/how_6232435_remove-spray-paint-asphalt.html) recommends a combination of pressure washer, mineral spirit, and scrubbing with a wire brush.

Comment: A wire brush!? on blacktop!?  The mineral spirits also scares me that it would damage the seal coat.